# Get Angular 6 singleton service outside of Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Is there a way to get a handle on an Angular service from outside Angular code?  Specifically I'm thinking of for testing purposes from a testing framework.

I would like to be able to get a reference to a service and stub/mock functions within it.

Is that possible?  It feels like it should be, even if it's via the window object or similar?

**Edit for clarification:**

I am writing tests where the intention is for completely mocked data to be returned to the UI so no interaction with the server is required.  This is proving easy for the XHR calls, but not for interactions with a websocket.  We have a service for managing the interaction with the websocket, so my idea was to mock some of that service so that it can send back the mocked data and not go to the server.  I'm just struggling to see if or how this could be done, at all.

Comment: The Angular framework also provides testing functionality via the `TestBed`, which allows you to configure the DI however you need it. See https://angular.io/guide/testing#testing-services-with-the-testbed

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have attempted to use TestBed, but it hasn't so far achieved what I would like.  It could be I'm using it incorrectly, but it doesn't appear to return the instance of a service being used by the UI that is running.  It seems to return a new instance of the service to unit test with, which is what TestBed appears to be designed for.  Do you think it can be used to get a handle on the instance the UI is using instead somehow, to assist with running E2E tests for instance?

Comment: You shouldn't be replacing *anything* in E2E tests, that's why they're called end-to-end. Perhaps you should [edit] to explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: Apologies, I think it is my use of E2E in my last comment that is misleading, somewhat.  I am writing tests where the intention is for completely mocked data to be returned to the UI so no interaction with the server is required.  This is proving easy for the XHR calls, but not for interactions with a websocket.  We have a service for managing the interaction with the websocket, so my idea was to mock some of that service so that it can send back the mocked data and not go to the server.  I'm just struggling to see if or how this could be done, at all.